# How to distinguish flash drives?

Tags: delphi, usb

Good day.

I need some help. I want to make program in Delphi, and one of functions of this program: distinguish flash drives. For example: I connect new flash drive to computer, my program detect it too, I give to this flash drive some name ONLY in my program. Next, I can change anything: name of flash drive in Windows, content at this flash drive, format it. But after this actions my program should detect this flash drive and show me name, that I gave to it.

May be, there is some serial number, unique for any device/falsh drive? Or something like that.

Will be very grateful for your help =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look here:
[Data exchange directy to USB device with VID and PID in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360527/data-exchange-directy-to-usb-device-with-vid-and-pid-in-delphi)

You could read the Vendor ID, and Product ID of the thumbdrive.  This will at least give you the brand and make of the thumbdrive.  I don't think it will be unique to each thumbdrive of the same type though.

It looks like these might also be right up your alley:

[How to find the unique serial number of a flash device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930008/how-to-find-the-unique-serial-number-of-a-flash-device)

[How to get manufacturer serial number of an USB flash drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292395/get-usb-serial-number-without-wmi-in-delphi)

Comment: thank you. read this questions and read questions, which I find in this questions; find answer =)